# Exception MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json on upgrading to Jersey 2.29.1

Tags: json, jersey, jersey-2.0, java-11

I have recently upgraded an application from Jersey 1.19 to 2.29.1 and added the following dependencies during the upgrade.

```
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

On running application I am getting the following exception trace

```
 Exception Message: NotSupportedException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type, Stack Trace: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)

Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json,
```

Is jersey-media-json-processing correct dependency for JSON or if there is any thing else which needs to be added?

Comment: Remove `jersey-media-json-processing` and add `jersey-media-json-jackson`

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I was using 'jersey-media-json-jackson` but then I couldn't find any reference if it is auto-discoverable. In the [usr guide] (https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.autodiscoverable) they have mentioned only 3 dependencies which are auto-discoverable by default. If `jersey-media-json-jackson` gets added  in the pom is that suffiecient or does it needs to be registered through code as well ?

Comment: Adding it is enough. Look in the module and you will see a class JacksonAutoDiscoverab;e. That's how you know it's autodiscoverable.